# XSL double xml element

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I hope somebody can tell me why I do get 2 E1EDT20 elements in my result? Must be doing a copy too many but I can't figure it out.

**My input xml**

```
<SHPMNT05>
   <IDOC BEGIN="1">
      <EDI_DC40 SEGMENT="1">
         <TABNAM>EDI_DC40</TABNAM>
      </EDI_DC40>
      <E1EDT20 SEGMENT="1">
         <TKNUM>0000287214</TKNUM>
         <E1EDL20 SEGMENT="1">
            <VBELN>0081018702</VBELN>
            <ABLAD>1</ABLAD>
            <VSTEL>EWM</VSTEL>
            <VKORG>0100</VKORG>
         </E1EDL20>
         <E1EDL20 SEGMENT="1">
            <VBELN>0081018703</VBELN>
            <ABLAD>1</ABLAD>
            <VSTEL>EWM</VSTEL>
            <VKORG>0210</VKORG>
         </E1EDL20>
      </E1EDT20>
   </IDOC>
</SHPMNT05>
```

**My XSL**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
   
     <xsl:template match="E1EDT20">
       
       
       <xsl:copy>
      
    <xsl:copy-of select="*[not(self::E1EDL20)]"/>
       
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:for-each-group select="E1EDL20" group-adjacent="concat(ABLAD, '|', VKORG)" >
            <CMR>
              <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
            </CMR>
         </xsl:for-each-group>
      </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:copy>
      
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My current result looks like:

```
<SHPMNT05>
   <IDOC BEGIN="1">
      <EDI_DC40 SEGMENT="1">
         <TABNAM>EDI_DC40</TABNAM>
      </EDI_DC40>
      <E1EDT20>
         <TKNUM>0000287214</TKNUM>
         <E1EDT20>
            <CMR>
               <E1EDL20 SEGMENT="1">
                  <VBELN>0081018702</VBELN>
                  <ABLAD>1</ABLAD>
                  <VSTEL>EWM</VSTEL>
                  <VKORG>0100</VKORG>
               </E1EDL20>
            </CMR>
            <CMR>
               <E1EDL20 SEGMENT="1">
                  <VBELN>0081018703</VBELN>
                  <ABLAD>1</ABLAD>
                  <VSTEL>EWM</VSTEL>
                  <VKORG>0210</VKORG>
               </E1EDL20>
            </CMR>
         </E1EDT20>
      </E1EDT20>
   </IDOC>
</SHPMNT05>
```

Required result

```
<SHPMNT05>
    <IDOC BEGIN="1">
        <EDI_DC40 SEGMENT="1">
            <TABNAM>EDI_DC40</TABNAM>
        </EDI_DC40>
        <E1EDT20>
            <TKNUM>0000287214</TKNUM>
            <CMR>
                <E1EDL20 SEGMENT="1">
                    <VBELN>0081018702</VBELN>
                    <ABLAD>1</ABLAD>
                    <VSTEL>EWM</VSTEL>
                    <VKORG>0100</VKORG>
                </E1EDL20>
            </CMR>
            <CMR>
                <E1EDL20 SEGMENT="1">
                    <VBELN>0081018703</VBELN>
                    <ABLAD>1</ABLAD>
                    <VSTEL>EWM</VSTEL>
                    <VKORG>0210</VKORG>
                </E1EDL20>
            </CMR>
        </E1EDT20>
    </IDOC>
</SHPMNT05>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFksq1t

I'm almost there (thanks to your stack support :) ) must be doing something stupid here..

Kind regards,

Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as you say, you have two `xsl:copy`:

```
<xsl:template match="E1EDT20">
   
   
   <xsl:copy>
  
<xsl:copy-of select="*[not(self::E1EDL20)]"/>
   
  <xsl:copy>
```

Comment: I feel / am stupid Martin. Might delete the post but thanks a million